# Can't compile kernel on vbox

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm installing Linux kernel 5.14.1 on Vbox. After `make` I'm getting this error:

```
FAILED:load btf from vmlinux
```

I executed the command `sudo apt install dwarves` before the `make` command. Still getting the error.

Comment: One suggestion is to increase the amount of memory allocated to the vm.

Comment: I have already allocated max possible which is 2 gb in my case

Comment: Then I doubt you have enough memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [failed: load btf from vmlinux: invalid argument make on CONFIG\_DEBUG\_INFO\_BTF=y](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/754325/failed-load-btf-from-vmlinux-invalid-argument-make-on-config-debug-info-btf-y)