# failed: load btf from vmlinux: invalid argument make on CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y

Tags: kernel, compiling

I just got the following error when compiling `linux-5.14.2.tar.gz` and `patch-5.14.2-rt21.patch`

```
 on CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y:

      AS      arch/x86/lib/iomap_copy_64.o
    arch/x86/lib/iomap_copy_64.S: Assembler messages:
    arch/x86/lib/iomap_copy_64.S:13: 警告：found `movsd'; assuming `movsl' was meant
      AR      arch/x86/lib/built-in.a
      GEN     .version
      CHK     include/generated/compile.h
      LD      vmlinux.o
    ld: warning: arch/x86/power/hibernate_asm_64.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
    ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker
      MODPOST vmlinux.symvers
      MODINFO modules.builtin.modinfo
      GEN     modules.builtin
      LD      .tmp_vmlinux.btf
    ld: warning: arch/x86/power/hibernate_asm_64.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
    ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker
    ld: warning: .tmp_vmlinux.btf has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions
      BTF     .btf.vmlinux.bin.o
      LD      .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1
    ld: warning: .btf.vmlinux.bin.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
    ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker
    ld: warning: .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1 has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions
      KSYMS   .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.S
      AS      .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1.S
      LD      .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2
    ld: warning: .btf.vmlinux.bin.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
    ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker
    ld: warning: .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2 has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions
      KSYMS   .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.S
      AS      .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.S
      LD      vmlinux
    ld: warning: .btf.vmlinux.bin.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
    ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker
    ld: warning: vmlinux has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions
      BTFIDS  vmlinux

    failed: load btf from vmlinux: invalid argument make:
    make: *** [Makefile:1176: vmlinux] Error 255
    make: *** Deleting file 'vmlinux'
```

I know that if `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF` is set to `n`, compilation will not report errors, but I don't want `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF` to be set to `n`.

From [this issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616392/failed-load-btf-from-vmlinux-unknown-error-2make-makefile1162-vmlinu), it seems that the virtual memory is too small, but the initiator of this problem is using a virtual machine, and I am a physical machine Debian12. What should I do?

```shellsession
~/kernel/5.14.2/linux-5.14.2$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
内存：         7.7Gi       508Mi       3.4Gi       1.2Mi       4.1Gi       7.2Gi
交换：         976Mi          0B       976Mi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing the kernel version.

**linux-6.4.tar.gz** and **patch-6.4.6-rt8.patch**.

Answer (score 1):

This likely happened because you were using `pahole` 1.24 or newer with an "older" kernel version. See https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/Ywkq61Lhyf11SsSa@krava/T/#m008baf5c6d4f252dc74cefcd4105295cf08bfd52

In short, the newer version of `pahole` on your system generated BTF information using `BTF_KIND_ENUM64`, but the `libbpf` used in those older kernel versions doesn't support this BTF type.

You could try to downgrade `pahole` to version 1.23 or find where `pahole` is being invoked in the build and pass the `--skip_encoding_btf_enum64` flag to it.

Note for anyone that has a similar error in the future: there is useful information reported in `pr_debug` calls in the `resolve_btfids` tool, if you increase the log level so they're actually printed it will help to determine what the issue is.